# Adding multiple projects to solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

This seems to be extremely annoying. I create a blank solution and add an existing project or website to it and then the solution folder disappears and it just shows the added project, so I can't add any more projects or websites to the solution...

Update **

I'm not sure if this was from an extension or just by default, but in the Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions I found an option called "Always show solution" and it was unchecked. When I checked it the solution folder appeared so that I could right-click on it to add additional projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set studio to always show the solution

From the menu: Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions
Check the option: **Always show solution**

Answer (score 1):

just open solution file > open solution .. then right click the solution folder > add project

[Step by step](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173814.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an existing project simply going to File  -> Add -> Existing Project....

This works and your solution will reappear in the Solution Explorer

Answer (score 1):

This may be because of the *"Always Show Solution"* setting that may be unchecked.

It can be found in the menu in *Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General*.

When unchecked, it'll hide the solution item when there is one project ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/26/hide-or-show-the-solution-in-solution-explorer-vstipproj0008.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use VS express and there is restriction You can create just 1 project there.

Answer (score 0):

To create a project and add it to a solution:

1. In **Solution Explorer**, choose the solution or the solution folder to which you want to add a project that you create.
2. On the menu bar, choose **File, Add, New Project**.
3. In the left pane, select **Installed**, and select a category of project types from the expanded list.
4. Select one of the project **Templates** from the middle pane.
5. In the **Name** box, type a name for the new project and then select **OK**.

Read [How to: Create Multi-Project Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h970wzkb.aspx) for more information.