# Visual Studio not creating a solution file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, solution

I've just opened VS 2010 Professional up on my machine, started a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project and noticed that it doesn't seem to be creating a Solution file. This means I can't - or don't seem to be able to add a new project to the solution as its not there!

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate the problem:

[image]

I've just tried creating a number of other new projects i.e a WinForm, console app and a class library and all have the same issue, no sln.

Can anyone give me an indication of whats going on?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20669557/390819) may help

Comment: @w0lf Thank you! Please put this as your answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio will hide the solution item in Solution Explorer if there's only one project.

To change this, go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General and make sure "Always Show Solution" is checked.

Comment: Hi, "Always Show Solution" no longer exists in VS 2022. All there is in that menu is (names cut short for comment length):
"Show Error List if build errors
Track Active ltem
Show Output when build starts
Prompt before moving files
Allow parallel project initialization
Reopen documents on load
Restore Explorer hierarchy state on load
Open project files with double-click / Enter

Rename symbolically
Prompt for symbolic renaming

Enable namespace update when moving files
Prompt to update namespace".

I also did a search bar query for what you said, there is no such option.